# Getting last element in same line

Tags: jquery, insertafter

I have this code where i want to insert the div after the line in which element is present.I'm able to do do this for the last element in the line. The problem is i'm not able to figure how to do it for rest of the elements in same line

HTML

```
<div class="wrap">
  <div class="info"></div>
    <div class="info"></div>
    <div class="info"></div>
    <div class="info"></div>
    <div class="info"></div>
    <div class="info"></div>
    <div class="info"></div>
    <div class="info"></div>
    <div class="info"></div>
    <div class="info"></div>
    <div class="info"></div>
    <div class="info"></div>
    <div class="info"></div>
    <div class="info"></div>

    <div class="newdiv"></div>
```

CSS

```
.wrap{border:1px solid #000;width:630px}
.info{border:1px solid red; width:180px;float:left;margin-left:20px;height:100px;margin-top:20px}
.newdiv{width:100%;height:100px;background:green;display:none;float:left}
.active{background:brown}
```

Jquery

```
$('.info').on('click',function(){
  $('.info').removeClass('active');
  $(this).addClass('active');

  if(($(this).index('.info')+1)%3===0)
  {
    $('.newdiv').insertAfter($(this)).show();
  }

});
```

Demo http://jsbin.com/AvERUpU/1/

Comment: @undefined See the demo u will understand . there are 3 divs in a line. When clicked on div<3 show after last element in line ie line 1. when clicked less than 6 show after last element in that line ie line 2

Comment: @Ace I don't have the time to make a sample right now, but you can use the module to detect if it is the first, second or third in the row. Then you can use `.nextAll('.info')` to find the element where you need to insert.

Comment: @undefined tnx . i'm using index for the first time, didnt know how to use it properly.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Calculate the index of the 3thd element:

```
  var index = $(this).index('.info');
  var afterIndex = index - index % 3 + 2;
  var all = $('.info');
  if (afterIndex >= all.length) {
     afterIndex = all.length - 1;
  }
  $('.newdiv').insertAfter(all.eq(afterIndex)).show();
```

http://jsbin.com/AvERUpU/4/

Answer (score 1):

Just a simple math.

Try this,

```
$('.info').on('click',function(){
  $('.info').removeClass('active');
  $(this).addClass('active'); 
  var xIndexAdded = $(this).index('.info') + (2 - ($(this).index('.info')%3));     
  $('.newdiv')
     .insertAfter(($('.info').eq((xIndexAdded>=$('.info').length)?$('.info').length-1:xIndexAdded))) 
     .show();  
});
```

### [DEMO](http://jsbin.com/AvERUpU/12)

Comment: @Ace Fixed the issue.!